# NaN in excel cell generating error when reading with pandas: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was able to identify the issue but not the solution when using:

```
pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name)

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Problem is that I have a column full of numbers with decimal cases (floats) and in some rows I have "NaN" and that is causing the error, but do not really know how to solve it.
Ideas?

Comment: Why is it trying to covert to an integer? Try add `dtype="float"`. Or `convert_float=False`. According to the docs it should recognize the string `"NaN"` as a missing value by default

Comment: If the previous comment doesn't answer your question, please add a minimal example of the excel.

Comment: convert_float = False seems to work